# Sort LibreOffice Calc rows through all columns

Tags: libreoffice, sorting, openoffice-calc

I have a list of items with set of properties. Some of the properties are unique, some are the same. I want to sort the properties through all items to see which items have equal properties.
Maybe it's not so clear what I want to do, so I will try to clarify with screenshots.

Items with properties: [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYaip.png)

After sorting: [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0hCW.png)

Here I can see which items have similar properties.

Comment: It sounds illogical and impossible. Are you able to massively expand your example? How many rows is this? Have your tried concatenating all into a fifth column and sorting by that?

Answer (score 0):

In column E, in E3:
= A3 && B3 && C3 && D3

Copy that down the column; Then copy paste as values "text"; sort by column E, alphabetic.